# count user from different districts by selected age

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write mysql query that would get me the data about the count of users in my different districts by some selcted age . 
for example : if i choose age 0-14 i want to get how many users from 'north' ,'south' and etc are between age 0 and 14.

i'm writing the current query :

```
SELECT sum(case when districts.`districtId` = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as 'North',
    sum(case when districts.`districtId` = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as 'Center',
    sum(case when  districts.`districtId` = 6 then 1 else 0 end) as 'South', , (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(userDetails.birthDate2, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(userDetails.birthDate2, '00-%m-%d'))) as age
```

from .... where age between 0 and 14 
but i get the error : unknown age column. 
is there other way to write this query ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT districts.districtId, count(userDetails.*)
FROM userDetails, districts
INNER JOIN districts ON userDetails.districtId = districts.districtId
WHERE userDetails.birthDate2 >= (DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 YEAR)
AND userDetails.birthDate2 <= (DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 0 YEAR)
GROUP BY districts.districtId
```

And for your other question, try to post the database schema..

EDIT :
I Forgotten the `GROUP BY` Clausse

Comment: Of course, in the above answer by AlonsoFloo, add the Group By clause.

Comment: if i replace your select with mine. it works . thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't give the full query, try this, filling in with your values :

```
 Select districts.districtId, count(*) as DistrictwiseCount From ... Where age_criterion_goes_here
    Group By districts.districtId
```